# Unable to connect to Mysql from Django app - AWS, EC2, RDS

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am having trouble connecting to my RDS MySQL Database.

My current Set up:

Django 1.9+

AWS - Launched an EC2 Instance (Amazon Linux).  Launched an RDS instance of MySQL (5.6.7).  I created a Virtual PC (VPC) for the EC2 instance and RDS instance, and in that group created several security rules so the EC2 instance could connect to the MySQL RDS.  Below are the security rules I use and associate with the VPC.

```
    Inbound Rules: (Type, Protocol, Port Range, Source)
    1. Http , TCP, 80 , 0.0.0.0/0
    2. SSH , TCP, 22 , <homePC address>/32
    3. HTTPS, TCP, 443, 0.0.0.0/0
    4. MYSQL/Aurora, TCP, 3306, source (my created security group)
```

Nginx - Serving my content redirecting from port 80 to port 443.  I created SSL certificates in order to make my site secure.  I correctly served my Django application, and the static files.  Nginx serves everything great!

Previously I was able to connect to my RDS instance.  I did not set up an elastic IP at that point in time, as it took some time to transfer my domain over to Route53 (amazons DNS).  I successfully was able to transfer it, and associate it with my EC2 instance and even start my application

The problems -
**First Problem** I cannot connect to the RDS from my EC2 instance.  I have checked my django settings file and the secret file (the one that feeds my settings file with sensitive information which I keep out of version control). Here are examples of my settings for the mysql connection - I changed them obviously

```
    "DATABASE_NAME":"myDatabase",
    "DATABASE_USERNAME": "myUsername",
    "DATABASE_PASSWORD": "myPassword123",
```

I double checked the username and password in the RDS console, and even reset the password.

After I went ahead and activated my virtual environment and attempted to connect.

```
    python manage.py dbshell
```

My Error was

```
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myUsername'@'<private IP address from Elastic IP>' (using password: YES)
```

Notive the user name is *not* what I utilized in the settings.   It changed.  I feel this is the root cause of the problem, but am unsure why Django would change my username in such a manner.

**Second Problem** -  I also try to connect to the database directly using mysql.  I double check my endpoint, username and password are correct, but also run into trouble connecting.

Note - As I said, I was able to connect in both manners listed above before acquiring my IP address.  Thus my troubles are configuring security rules to allow a permanent IP address, and being unable to use TCP connect to use the Mysql client to log in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additional observation - the Private IP address from the elastic IP is what is appending itself to the username and causing login problems.

Comment: its not appending itself to the username. Read mysql manual about  GRANTs. I usually add a grant for 'myUsername'@'%', cause those private IPs can change in a autoscale environment. Secure the RDS instance by having it in private subnet (no route to igw) and use security groups. To use mysql cli I ssh into the ec2 instance or bastion host.

Comment: I followed an AWS tutorial to create the VPC, the database, and the running EC2 instance.  This involved creating the private subnets for the VPC in question.  However when I launched the new DB instance wizard, it simply had me input the user name.  If I was creating the DB by myself, I would manually do it as you said , 'myuser'@'localhost' than grant privileges.    Finally as outlined above, my security groups were created.  Still unsure why I am unable to log in now, when previously I was able to do so prior

Comment: Solved:  Your solution to add a grant for your username was correct.  I was more specific and added the internal IP of my EC2 instance, and it worked.  However the key was logging in via my ec2 instance and adding the user with the correct privileges , which my Django app could than log in without a problem.   In regards to the second problem, since there are no outside connections allowed, there is no way my MySQL client on my dev PC could connect.  At least not with the security rules I had in place.